# Subdividing blender planes

Tags: edit-mode

I wish to divide up a plane in the ratio 1:2:2 .. Can that be done?

Loop cuts seem to divide the plane equally and simply slide in the same proportion

Comment: Could you show a screenshot or sketch of desired subdivision ? I'm not sure I understand how ratio "1:2:2" for the plane looks like.

Comment: Have you tried: 

Edit mode->Select all->press 'W'->Subdivide

?

Comment: Indeed, how does a 1:2:2 ratio look like on a flat plane?

Comment: you could try to use the "loop cut and slide" (CRTL-R) tool, create 4 cuts, then select the 2 pairs of vertices that you don't need, and "dissolve" them using CTRL-X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of what I meant in my comment above:

1. use the "loop cut and slide" (<kbd>CRTL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) tool to create 4 cuts
2. then select the 2 pairs of vertices that you don't need, and "dissolve" them using <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create your plane
Using <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd> add 3 cuts to the plane on both **X** & **Y** axis
[image: Cuts to Plane]

Now, leave the first 2 cuts on both sides and press <kbd>X</kbd> to get the delete menu.
Ensure, You select "Dissolve Edges" & "Dissolve Vertex" in corresponding command options (Visible in Tools Menu)
[image: Planes Cut]
Your Desired Plane is Cut in 1:2:2